# remove app icon from taskbar and put it in tray when making a widget in python

Tags: python, widget, pyinstaller

I made a windows widget in python and I convert it to an exe file using `pyinstaller` and made a shortcut and put it in the startup folder.

> The command:
>
> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myapp.py

So my app runs in the system startup. It shows the app icon in the taskbar but I want to see it only in the tray like all windows widgets.

> EDIT: In fact, I want to let it run in the background.

How can I do That? Should I change the `pyinstaller` command?

Thanks for your help.